Passing state down to a mapped child element
I am new to react so please be kind.
I have an accordion that shows searched terms, I am trying to pass a state down to each child within this accordion but I can't seem to get the state to toggle when the child is clicked.
So far I have my accordion (I have removed the code around it):
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

 const toggleAccordion = () => {
     setIsOpen(!isOpen)   
 }

return (
  <div className='grid'>
    {enableSearch && searchComponents}
    {accordionData.length > 0
      ? (
        <section className='accordion' data-kontent-item-id={id}>
          {title &&
            <h2 className='accordion__title'>{title}</h2>}
          {accordionData.map(
            (item, key) =>
              item.title && (
                <AccordionItem
                  key={key}
                  title={item.title}
                  text={item.text}
                  itemId={item.id}
                  onClick={toggleAccordion}
                  onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                  isOpen={isOpen}
               />
              )
          )}
        </section>
        )
      : (
          enableSearch && (
            <div
              className='mt-8'
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: noResultsText }}
            />
          )
        )}
  </div>
)

And my accordion item:
const AccordionItem = ({ title, text, itemId, isOpen }) => {

 const contentRef = useRef(null)

  return (
    <div className={`accordion__item ${isOpen ? 'accordion__item-label--expanded' : ''}`} data-kontent-item-id={itemId}>
      <div
        className='accordion__item-label js-accordion__item-label'
        tabIndex={0}
      >
      </div>
      <div
        className='accordion__item-content js-accordion__item-content'
        ref={contentRef}
      >
        <div className='accordion__item-content-wrapper' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

I would like the isOpen state to change when the accordion item is clicked. I am not getting any errors.

AccordionItem should pass the onClick prop to an actual DOMNode like a button element so that when it is clicked it can toggle the state.
Example:
const AccordionItem = ({
  onClick,
  title,
  text,
  itemId,
  isOpen
}) => {
  const contentRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className={`accordion__item ${isOpen ? 'accordion__item-label--expanded' : ''}`} data-kontent-item-id={itemId}>
      <div
        className='accordion__item-label js-accordion__item-label'
        tabIndex={0}
      >
      </div>

      <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
        Toggle Accordion
      </button>

      <div
        className='accordion__item-content js-accordion__item-content'
        ref={contentRef}
      >
        <div className='accordion__item-content-wrapper' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

The next issue you'll hit though is that you are using a single isOpen state that is passed to all accordion components and they will all be toggled together. My suggestion would be to change isOpen from a boolean value to either a nullable string/number type that coincides with the specific accordion you want to have toggled open, or to use an object if you want more than one accordion open at a time.
Example:
Single open accordion:
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(null);

const toggleAccordion = (id) => {
  setIsOpen(isOpen => isOpen === id ? null : id);
}

{accordionData
  .filter(item => item.title)
  .map((item) => (
    <AccordionItem
      key={item.id}
      title={item.title}
      text={item.text}
      itemId={item.id}
      onClick={() => toggleAccordion(item.id)}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      isOpen={isOpen === item.id}
    />
  )
)}

Multiple open accordion:
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState({});

const toggleAccordion = (id) => {
  setIsOpen(isOpen => ({
    ...isOpen,
    [id]: !isOpen[id],

  }));
}

{accordionData
  .filter(item => item.title)
  .map((item) => (
    <AccordionItem
      key={item.id}
      title={item.title}
      text={item.text}
      itemId={item.id}
      onClick={() => toggleAccordion(item.id)}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      isOpen={isOpen[item.id]}
    />
  )
)}


Thank you for the reply, I have passed the onClick prop to the surrounding div but now when I click 1 they all open.

@mop333 Yeah, I knew that'd be your next issue and wasn't sure if I should call it out or leave it for you to figure out. Basically you have the one single state controlling all accordions. Does your accordion data have a handy id property to uniquely identify it?

Yes, I have the itemId that I am passing in.

You can create a state in the Accordion that stores an object lookup that maps the accordion data id to a boolean.
Every time you toggle the item, it will invert the inner state.
const [openMap, setOpenMap] = useState({});

const toggleOpen = (id) => {
  setOpenMap((currOpenMap) => {
    return {
      ...currOpenMap,
      [id]: !currOpenMap[id],
    };
  });
};

The following should work:
import Accordion from "./components/Accordion";

const accordionData = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Accordion Item 1",
    text: "<p>Accordion Item 1 Content</p>",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Accordion Item 2",
    text: "<p>Accordion Item 2 Content</p>",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "Accordion Item 3",
    text: "<p>Accordion Item 3 Content</p>",
  },
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Accordion
        title="Accordian Title"
        data={accordionData}
        enableSearch
        searchComponents
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import { useState } from "react";
import AccordionItem from "./AccordionItem";

const id = 1;
const noResultsText = "No results found";

function handleKeyDown(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.target.click();
  }
}

export default function Accordion({
  title,
  data,
  enableSearch,
  searchComponents,
}) {
  const [openMap, setOpenMap] = useState({});

  const toggleOpen = (id) => {
    setOpenMap((currOpenMap) => {
      return {
        ...currOpenMap,
        [id]: !currOpenMap[id],
      };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="grid">
      {enableSearch && searchComponents}
      {data.length > 0 ? (
        <section className="accordion" data-kontent-item-id={id}>
          {title && <h2 className="accordion__title">{title}</h2>}
          {data.map(
            (item, key) =>
              item.title && (
                <AccordionItem
                  key={key}
                  title={item.title}
                  text={item.text}
                  itemId={item.id}
                  toggleOpen={toggleOpen}
                  onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                  isOpen={openMap[item.id]}
                />
              )
          )}
        </section>
      ) : (
        enableSearch && (
          <div
            className="mt-8"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: noResultsText }}
          />
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import { useCallback, useRef } from "react";

export default function AccordionItem({ text, itemId, isOpen, toggleOpen }) {
  const contentRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    toggleOpen(itemId);
  }, [itemId, toggleOpen]);

  return (
    <div
      className={`accordion__item ${
        isOpen ? "accordion__item-label--expanded" : ""
      }`}
      data-kontent-item-id={itemId}
    >
      <div
        className="accordion__item-label js-accordion__item-label"
        tabIndex={0}
      ></div>

      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Toggle Accordion
      </button>

      <div
        className="accordion__item-content js-accordion__item-content"
        ref={contentRef}
      >
        <div
          className="accordion__item-content-wrapper"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

.accordion__item .accordion__item-content {
  display: none;
}

.accordion__item.accordion__item-label--expanded .accordion__item-content {
  display: block;
}

